# How to auto fill column down in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How can I auto fill a column down, e.g., *Cell(A1).value = dog* and *Cell(A12).value = Pen*

How do I fill down *A2:A11* with the value = *dog* and the A13 value = *pen* without manually selecting the column?

```
Sub filldown_example()
    Dim missingcells as range
    Dim fillsedcells as range

    Set missingcells = select

    For each filledcells in missingcells

        If filledcells = "" Then
            filledcells.filldown
        End If

    Next filledcells

End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need VBA for this. If you search Google for *Excel fill all blanks with cell above* you will get the *non*-VBA method.

If you still want VBA, then try this. You do not need to loop through all cells.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        '~~> Find the last row in Col A and add 1 to it
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        '~~> Find the blank cells
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        On Error GoTo 0

        '~~> Add the formula to get values from the above cell in 1 go
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"

        '~~> Convert formulas to values
        .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value = .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

**In Action:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Fill Down Selection

This will allow you to select multiple ranges with multiple columns to fill down each of them.

**Range**

```
Sub FillDownSelectionRange()

    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub

    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Selection

    Dim arg As Range ' Area Range
    Dim crg As Range ' Column Range
    Dim rCell As Range ' Row Cell Range
    Dim rValue As Variant

    For Each arg In rg.Areas
        For Each crg In arg.Columns
            If crg.Rows.Count > 1 Then
                For Each rCell In crg.Cells
                    If Len(CStr(rCell.Value)) = 0 Then
                        rCell.Value = rValue
                    Else
                        If rCell.Value <> rValue Then
                            rValue = rCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next rCell
            End If
            rValue = Empty
        Next crg
    Next arg

End Sub
```

**Array**

To speed up, instead of looping through the cells, you could loop through an array.

```vb
Sub FillDownSelectionArray()

    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub

    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Selection

    Dim arg As Range ' Area Range
    Dim crg As Range ' Column Range
    Dim cData As Variant ' Column Array
    Dim rValue As Variant
    Dim r As Long

    For Each arg In rg.Areas
        For Each crg In arg.Columns
            If crg.Rows.Count > 1 Then
                cData = crg.Value
                For r = 1 To UBound(cData, 1)
                    If IsEmpty(cData(r, 1)) Then
                        cData(r, 1) = rValue
                    Else
                        If cData(r, 1) <> rValue Then
                            rValue = cData(r, 1)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next r
                crg.Value = cData
            End If
            rValue = Empty
        Next crg
    Next arg

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop here.

```
Sub fillit()

    With Range("a1:a13")
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
        .Value = .Value   'formula to value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70389716/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).